# Android table with huge data: TableLayout or RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

So I wanted to create a table with 10 columns that has an endless scroll. But when using `TableLayout` doesn't it get heavy when it loads a lot of data as it doesn't has view recycling?

But if I had to use `RecyclerView`, how to make that every row items has the same column weight? I cannot use weight in item layout, because it contains 10 columns so it needs to be horizontal scrolled. I also do not want to use a fixed width because I don't know how long the text in each column is.

Is there any solution to this?
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

adding a gridlayoutmanager to your recyclerview with 10 columns

Comment: but is'nt GridLayoutManager uses different data for each of their items? I wanted to use 1 object data for each row which contains name, address etc.